# Create CCTexture2D from a CCSprite with primitives being drawn in draw method

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a `CCSprite` subclass. In the draw method, I am drawing some `cocos2d` primitives like lines and such. How can I create a `CCTexture2D` of the sprite? I can't use `sprite.texture` because that doesn't include the primitives I am drawing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add sprite to object of CCRenderTexture2D and after this can draw sprite to texture.

look at the example

```
CCSprite *spr = nil;//your sprite
CCRenderTexture* renderTexture = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:spr.contentSize.width height:spr.contentSize.height];

spr.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
spr.position = ccp(0, 0);
[renderTexture addChild:spr];  

[renderTexture begin];     
[spr draw]; // or [spr visit];
[renderTexture end];

CCTexture2D *result = renderTexture.sprite.texture;
```

Now you will have texture, that contains sprite and primitives, that it draws in draw method.

Hope, it will help you:)